# Pyinstaller No module named pytube

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pytube

I am trying to make an executable here. I am trying to make a YouTube downloader and I am having a problem where when I open the app. It says:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you install pytube? `pip install pytube`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USE PIP INSTALL**:

```
 pip install pytube3
```

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! It works! but the program is not working as i expected though... no download

Comment: Though pytube3 didn't work but pytube did.